# Javascript if(function_foo()) doesn't wait for function_foo() to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement

I have an if statement:

```
    if(authenticate_session("secret_password12345")){
        alert("You are authenticated");
    }else{
        alert("Intruder alert!");
    }
```

and the javascript authenticate function, which makes an jQuery POST AJAX call to the server to do the actual authentication, and returns true or false:

```
function authenticate_session(session_id){
 $.post("/auth.php",
    { action: "authenticate_session", login_id: session_id },
    function(data){
        if(data == "denied"){
            alert("denied");
            return false;
        }else if(data == "accepted"){
        alert("accepted");
            return true;
        }
    },
"text");
}
```

However, when the if statement invokes the athentication function, it doesn't wait for the AJAX to complete, and always executes the 'else'. If I add 'return true;' into the first line of the authentication function, before the ajax, the if statement performs as expected => alert("You are authenticated").

I know that the server side is performing properly, as the alert("denied") and alert("accepted") are being called as expected (but interestingly, after the if statement alerts).

How can I make my if statement wait until the authentication function has completed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not waiting because it's an asynchronous request by default. Set the [`async` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) to `false` for it to be synchronous. From the docs:

> By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronous (i.e. this is set to true
>   by default). If you need synchronous
>   requests, set this option to false.
>   Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the
>   request is active.

Comment: This answer sounds spot on, but setting things to be synchronous actually did not fix the problem. Odd huh?

Comment: This, in conjunction with my answer, was the ticket.

Comment: You should never make synchronous calls from the browser. Exposing synchronous functionality when XHR is used in the browser was the single biggest mistake in the design of that component.

Answer (score 3):

i don't think you can make if statement "wait" for ajax, just move the this logic into ajax callback function (well, you actually did already : alert(denied|accepted))

Comment: I don't see why this asnwer hasn't been voted up yet. Synchronous 'Ajax' (Sjax?) calls are often a source of annoyance. Setting a callback function is a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is said before. Ajax does these kind of calls asynchronous. Waiting for it will may lock your browser (not desired).
So you should use a callback method to handle your data. This will keep your code responsible for doing the right stuff seperated.

```
function authenticate_session(session_id, callbacksuccess){
  $.post("/auth.php",
  { action: "authenticate_session", login_id: session_id },
  callback,
  "text");
}

function callback(data) {
  if (data == "denied") {
    alert('denied');
  } else if (data == "accepted") {
    alert('accepted');
  }
}

authenticate_session('secret_password12345", callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers.

The answer turned out to be that the return within the ajax method was returning out of the ajax method, not the authentication function.